# Onclick event with if-else function not working IE8

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer-8, onclick

So I have a ul with li, all which have an 'onclick' event assigned to them to execute function Highlight():

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
<li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

What I want: I want to, on click, change the background color of the clicked li to add a style with the color rgb(160, 216, 239), a light blue. Then when I click on it again, I want to remove the style.

The current function Highlight, is structured as following:

```
function highlight() {
        var elem = this;
        if(elem.style.backgroundColor != "rgb(160, 216, 239)"){
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(160, 216, 239)";
        }

        else{
        elem.removeAttribute("style");
    };
    }
```

It works perfectly in IE9-IE10, Firefox, Chrome, and pretty much everything. It doesn't work completely in IE8, which also needs to be supported. While the background DOES change the color, it DOES NOT remove the style or color again on the second click.

any thoughts?

Edit:

in the CSS, I also have:

```
li:hover{
background-color: #336699;
}
```

Comment: Does calling elem.getAttribute("style"); before removeAttribute() work?

Comment: Please show how you're binding the event.

Comment: @arnold.NET.JS who told you that? `rgb` is, `rgba` isn't AFAIK

Comment: WHat does `console.log(elem)` show?

Comment: @Barmar,  I am binding it with the .onclick event, as this one is the only one that truly works for almost every browser out there. So it would be, as an example, "li.onclick = highlight";

console.log(elem) returns "[object HTMLLIElement]" in IE10 in IE8 compatibility mode.

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa, Unfortunately, if I put that comment in the 'else' bracket before the elem.removeAttribute, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tested also in IE8**: **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hubug/5/edit)**

```
function highlight() { 
  var el = this;
  var io = el.highlighted ^= 1; // Simple 1/0 Toggler
  el.style.backgroundColor = io ? "rgb(160, 216, 239)" : "transparent" ;
}


var $li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i=0; i< $li.length; i++)
  $li[i].onclick = highlight;
```

This one works for me, so it's not an issue with `rgb()` <sup>( `rgba()` is not supported! )</sup>
but most likely in the way you assign your click event (i.e. **addEventListener in not supported in IE8**)

Comment: The click event worked the first time but not the second, meaning getting the background colour is the part that wasn't working. It should be done using a function such a getComputedStyle/getPropertyValue

Comment: Hello, thank you, this actually works. HOWEVER, I forgot to add that in the CSS, I have a li:hover, which changes the background color to a different one. So there are three stages: hover, click, click again. Using this works for the initial issue, however, when I 'hover' over it, it makes the innerHTML disappear as well. Let me put up an edit. Thanks though!

Comment: @user2588440 have you tried to use: `background-color: #336699 !important;` ? And btw in your comment you say that some HTML disappears... what could be possibly innerHTML had to do with styles?

Comment: I didn't mean the innerHTML data, I meant the text. It doesn't disappear from the DOM, it just becomes transparent now when I hover over it. Or rather, became. Adding the !important did the trick! Thank you.

What is that "^= 1" toggle? I've never heard of it before, it seems to make it work.